# display: none in <iframe> specific element

Tags: css, iframe, onload

In my html webpage I insert an iframe

but in this iframe bottom show a div which's class name `mobile-desktop-link`

[image: Picture]

Comment: Nice, did you tried it first? Perhaps by looking around on web?

Comment: i fed by many ways but no any found correct or simple way

Comment: You cannot do that with CSS, is jQuery solution fine for you?

Comment: if jquery its solution 
tell me how i extremely need solution !

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from your own domain?

Comment: Please post your HTML snippet in here so we can check it out. Fiddle it.

Comment: Download my page from bottom link
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9742598/iframe.html

in this html page in iframe i want hide bottom link where show 
**view web version**

you can see my problem in this image
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9742598/IFRAME.png

Comment: See my answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to hide the "view web version" link? Alright, than you can use this:

```
.mobile-desktop-link a.home-link { display: none; }
```

Add this to your stylesheet and you are ready to go. Of course this is only possible if the iFrame is on your domain. If you have tried the snippet I shared here above, with or without `!important` statement and it did not work? Well than, you can't remove it.

Comment: Can you show me what you tried? Did you use an `!important` statement too?

If it did not work, the `iframe` you are using must be coming from a different domain. In that case, you can't do it.

Comment: not working, 
some experts said on stackoverflow
You cannot do that with CSS, is jQuery solution fine for you? –  Mr. Alien 37 mins ago

Comment: You can do it with CSS, but only if the iframe is on your domain. I suppose that is not the case here. Yes, you can do it with jQuery, but I am not an expert on that one.